# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest freezes UI while downloading File

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a simple software updater PowerShell script which is working just fine,
recently I decided to add some GUI on it so I can hide the terminal windows while it's downloading the file while still letting the user know it's working.

ultimately I wanted to add download progress bar to be more informative, but for now my problem is that when using the `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $printer_link -OutFile $save_path -PassThru`
my UI freezes until the files are downloaded ( 4-5MB ). I tried putting it inside a JOB

my form is:

```
$form  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "POS Updater"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,160)
$form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form.TopMost = $true
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.StartPosition="CenterScreen"
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.Add_Shown({check_connection})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()
```

and my check_connection function :

```
function check_connection{
  $s =  iwr "google.com" | select statuscode, statusdescription
  $code = $s.statuscode
  if($code -eq 200){

   Start-Job -Name "sx" -ScriptBlock{
     $download =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $printer_link -OutFile $save_path -PassThru
   }

   while (Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.HasMoreData}) {
      Get-Job | Receive-Job
      [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() 
      Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }   
  }
}
```

but still, it freezes. How can I solve the problem, please..

Comment: Just a guess, but PowerShell kinda stop parsing while doing some things including something as arbitrary as highlighting something on the console so the fact that it takes time to run `iwr` may be the cause of the pausing/freezing

Comment: `Start-Sleep` causes freeze. You should look at a solution using a timer and check the result of `Get-Job` in its Tick({..}) event.